# How do I configure traefik properly for docker services on subdomains?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, subdomain, traefik

The example from the traefik quickstart guide for using the whoami image on the whoami subdomain works, but I can't get jellyfin working in a similar setup, and I can't figure out what's different:

```
kevin@pihost:~/personal$ curl -H Host:jellyfin.kevinm416.com http://127.0.0.1
Bad Gateway
kevin@pihost:~/personal$ curl -H Host:whoami.kevinm416.com http://127.0.0.1
Hostname: f7820e1787fe
IP: 127.0.0.1
...
```

This is my docker-compose file, which has all the traefik config:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  jellyfin-config:
  jellyfin-cache:

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: 
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.kevinm416.com`)"

  jellyfin:
    image: jellyfin/jellyfin
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      TZ: 'America/Los_Angeles'
    ports:
      - "8096:8096"
    volumes:
      - jellyfin-config:/config
      - jellyfin-cache:/cache
      - /home/kevin/microcenter:/microcenter:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.jellyfin.rule=Host(`jellyfin.kevinm416.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.jellyfin.loadbalancer.server.port=8096"
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there could be two problems:

1. you haven't specified entrypoints for your containers, e.g. for `whoami` it could be (maybe you want new one for jellyfin with port 8096?):

```
- "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
```

2. `network_mode: "host"` in jellyfin -- traefik should be in the same network as container (or try to use `traefik.docker.network` setting), so I would suggest just remove that line.